# Pull the rightmost string in parentheses

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data looks like this

```
ABCD.(123).(456)
789.(DEF) JKL.MNO
(PQ).(RS).(TUV)||(WXYz)
```

I am looking to pull the string from the RIGHTMOST parentheses brackets. Results would look like this

```
(456)
(DEF)
(WXYz)
```

The entire strings and strings within the parentheses can vary. Its some combination of substring and charindex, but i cannot figure it out.

Comment: Which RDMS are you working with?

Comment: Management Studio 2016

Comment: FYI - This data is all in one column.

Comment: Sql Server 2016 or just management studio 2016?  `select @@version`

Comment: @SqlZim Good question... I saw 2016 and assumed SQL Server 2016

Comment: SSMS 2016 is my rdms.

Answer (score 1):

Such a question suggests a problem with the data structure -- that the string actually consists of multiple items.  However, sometimes such string processing is necessary.

The following approach should work, assuming that a parenthesized component always exists:

```
select t.*, colparen
from t cross apply
     (values (right(col, charindex('(', reverse(col)) - 1)) v(colr) cross apply
     (values (charindex(colr, charindex(')', col) + 1)) v(colparen)
```

Comment: what does the COLPAREN and COLPARENT mean?

Comment: @baineschile . . . `colparen` is just the name of the result column.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are 2016, you can use **String_Split()** in concert with a **Cross Apply**.

Note:  Use Outer Apply if there are no observations and you want to display a null value.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('ABCD.(123).(456)'),
('789.(DEF).JKL.MNO'),
('(PQ).(RS).(TUV).(WXYz)')


Select B.Value
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
               Select Top 1 *
                     ,RN=Row_Number() over (Order By (Select Null))
                From String_Split(A.SomeCol,'.')
                Where Value Like '(%)'
                Order by 2 Desc
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Value
(456)
(DEF)
(WXYz)
```

**[dbFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a7caab689c6bed102f7d3a34bf58afcf)**

Answer (score 0):

```
select REVERSE(substring(reverse('ABCD.(123).(456)'),CHARINDEX(')',reverse('ABCD.(123).(456)')),CHARINDEX('(',reverse('ABCD.(123).(456)'))))
```

This should get you what you want